# Message Listener onMessage() method not red the message from Queue

Tags: java, jms

i am implementing the onMessgae () method of MessageListner Class but its not working even i am putting the debug point inside this method but debugger also not goes inside this method.

Use this method to receive the message from Queue.
Below is my code for receiving the message but its not giving any message when i am sending the message through sender class and its message goes to JMS Server and shows like this way on server

Name      Server   DestiCurrent MessagesCurrent MessagesPending MessagesReceived  JMSServer-0   AdminServer 3            15               1             2

Code for Reciver:

```
{
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


public class QueueReceive implements MessageListener {
    public final static String Server="t3://localhost:7001";
    public final static String JNDI_FACTORY = "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    public final static String JMS_FACTORY = "CF1";
    enter code here

    public final static String QUEUE = "Queue1";
    private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
    private QueueConnection qcon;
    private QueueSession qsession;
    private QueueReceiver qreceiver;
    private Queue queue;
    private boolean quit = false;
    String s1 = "avanish";


    public void init(Context ctx, String queueName) throws NamingException, JMSException {
        qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
        qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
        qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
        qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);
        qreceiver.setMessageListener(this);
        qcon.start();
        System.out.println(qreceiver.receive());
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
        qreceiver.close();
        qsession.close();
        qcon.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java examples.jms.queue.QueueReceive WebLogicURL");
            return;
        }*/
        InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();
        QueueReceive qr = new QueueReceive();
        qr.init(ic, QUEUE);
        System.out.println("JMS Ready To Receive Messages (To quit, send a \"quit\" message).");
        synchronized (qr) {
            while (!qr.quit) {
                try {
                    qr.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }
        qr.close();
    }


    private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, Server);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            String msgText;
            if(msg instanceof TextMessage){
                    msgText = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
                } 
             else{
                 msgText = msg.toString();
            }
                 System.out.println("reciver msg" + msgText);

                 if(msgText.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                     synchronized (this) {
                        quit= true;
                        this.notifyAll();
                    }
                 }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                System.err.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }


}

}
```

Code for Sender:
{

```
    import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.jms.*;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class QueueSend {
    public final static String Server="t3://localhost:7001";
    public final static String JNDI_FACTORY = "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    public final static String JMS_FACTORY = "CF1";
    public final static String QUEUE = "Queue1";
//  public final static String QUEUE = "DQ";
    private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
    private QueueConnection qcon;
    private QueueSession qsession;
    private QueueSender qsender;
    private Queue queue;
    private TextMessage msg;

    public void init(Context ctx, String queueName) throws NamingException, JMSException

    {

        qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);

        qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();

        qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);

        qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);

        msg = qsession.createTextMessage();

        qcon.start();

    }

    public void send(String message) throws JMSException {

        msg.setText(message);
        //msg.acknowledge();
        qsender.setPriority(9);
        qsender.send(msg);

    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {

        qsender.close();

        qsession.close();

        qcon.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        InitialContext ic = getInitialContext();

        QueueSend qs = new QueueSend();

        qs.init(ic, QUEUE);

        readAndSend(qs);

        qs.close();

    }

    private static void readAndSend(QueueSend qs) throws IOException, JMSException

    {

        BufferedReader msgStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = null;

        boolean quitNow = false;

        do {

            System.out.print("Enter message (\"quit\" to quit): \n");

            line = msgStream.readLine();

            if (line != null && line.trim().length() != 0) {

                qs.send(line);

                System.out.println("JMS Message Sent: " + line + "\n");

                quitNow = line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit");

            }

        } while (!quitNow);

    }

    private static InitialContext getInitialContext()

            throws NamingException

    {

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, Server);

        return new InitialContext(env);

    }

}



}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to ensure that the message is getting sent. Step through the sending code first to make sure it is getting to the line where you send the message.

Comment: @bremen_matt : Yes , server received the message whatever i send and after sending each message message count is alos increased at JMSSERVER.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear from your comment... So you can verify that the Server sends the message as well?

Comment: It would be good to post the server code as well. An obvious thing to do is to check that the port numbers in Server and receiver match.

Comment: @ bremen_matt  : port numbers are same for server and reciver. please find the below code for sending the message on server
{

Comment: @ bremen_matt : Please find the code for sending the message on server

Comment: No idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using MessageListener i used below lines of code and getting the exact message from queue

```
    queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);

   message = qreceiver.receiveNoWait();
```

its successfully received the messages from Queue.